# PHP: delete keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I have an array like this (result of var_export):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '96137742',
    'call' => '17',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '96161864',
    'call' => '5',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '88500737',
    'call' => '5',
  ),)
```

How can I get it as an array declaration like:

```
 array (

  array (
    'id' => '96137742',
    'call' => '17',
  ),

  array (
    'id' => '96161864',
    'call' => '5',
  ),
  array (
    'id' => '88500737',
    'call' => '5',
  ))
```

The thing is, I have a function where I have to put in the array values, and I don't want to do it by hand, is there any way I can do this automatically? The var_export() result would work if the first key wasn't the number of array.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying, but it sounds like you need to do `$array = array_values($array);`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your first and second arrays are same - because arrays in PHP are hashes, actually, so they'll have keys in _any case_. If you don't see them in your array's definition - that does not means they do not exist. If you're not defining keys, they will be _consecutive integers, starting from 0_

Answer (score 1):

I don't see differences between the first and second code.

In PHP,

```
array(0 => 'foo')
```

is same than

```
array('foo')
```